# VHDL, problems in using two variables to count

Tags: vhdl

I met a problem and I don't understand why...
for example, i make a declaration like this :

```vhdl
variable compteur1,compteur2 : natural range 0 to 15;
process(H)
begin
    if(rising_edge(H)) then
        compteur1 := compteur1 + 1;
        if (compteur1 = 9) then
            compteur2 := compteur2 + 1;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

Why does only compteur1 count normally from 0 to 15 while compteur2 runs just once?

Comment: That looks suspiciously as though there's a typo in the first line (*besides* the odd spelling of computer in general). Make sure there's no other errors in the retyped code, eh?

Comment: @NathanTuggy - I believe compteur is French for counter.  The issue is that there are simply spelling errors.  Kevin could have caught them.

Comment: @DavidKoontz Sure, but why would someone with a Chinese username be using French variable names?

Comment: @NathanTuggy  - Who cares?  There's this thing called free speech. Whle Bi Xing Zhou appears to be a Chinese name,  it could be a pseudonym or have other meaning.

Comment: @DavidKoontz ... free speech wat? Nothing at all to do with free speech; everything to do with whether it's a plausible assumption to make. "Typo" is more likely than "typo and also French despite non-French name and non-French post".

Comment: @NathanTuggy  - Try this then.  This is VHDL, a hardware description language, and in hardware design we have the idea of RTL hardware primitives which include among others things counters, which appears to match the very first instance. What train of logic did you arrive at 'computer' with?

Comment: haha, because I am a chinese student study in france...

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple things wrong, the rollover Kevin mentions, and there are some typos in the names:

This:

```
package compt is
    shared variable compteur1,compteur2 : natural range 0 to 15;
end package;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.compt.all;

entity foo is
end entity;

architecture fum of foo is
    signal H: std_logic := '0';
begin

CLOCK:
    process
    begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        H <= not H;
        if Now > 600 ns then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;

UNLABELLED:
    process(H)
    begin
        if(rising_edge(H)) then
            compteur1 := compteur1 + 1;
            report "compteur1 = " & natural'image(compteur1);
            if (compteur1 = 9) then
                compteur2 := compteur2 + 1;
                report "compteur2 = " & natural'image(compteur2);
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

gives a run time error because you increment compteur1 beyond it's bound:

> compteur.vhdl:31:13:@10ns:(report note): compteur1 = 1
>   compteur.vhdl:31:13:@30ns:(report note): compteur1 = 2
>   compteur.vhdl:31:13:@50ns:(report note): compteur1 = 3
>   compteur.vhdl:31:13:@70ns:(report note): compteur1 = 4
>   compteur.vhdl:31:13:@90ns:(report note): compteur1 = 5
>   compteur.vhdl:31:13:@110ns:(report note): compteur1 = 6
>   compteur.vhdl:31:13:@130ns:(report note): compteur1 = 7
>   compteur.vhdl:31:13:@150ns:(report note): compteur1 = 8
>   compteur.vhdl:31:13:@170ns:(report note): compteur1 = 9
>   compteur.vhdl:34:17:@170ns:(report note): compteur2 = 1
>   compteur.vhdl:31:13:@190ns:(report note): compteur1 = 10
>   compteur.vhdl:31:13:@210ns:(report note): compteur1 = 11
>   compteur.vhdl:31:13:@230ns:(report note): compteur1 = 12
>   compteur.vhdl:31:13:@250ns:(report note): compteur1 = 13
>   compteur.vhdl:31:13:@270ns:(report note): compteur1 = 14
>   compteur.vhdl:31:13:@290ns:(report note): compteur1 = 15
>   ./foo:error: bound check failure at compteur.vhdl:30
>   ./foo:error: simulation failed
>   ghdl: compilation error

Because VHDL doesn't have modular integer types and you're using a shared variable you can test where you increment:

```
UNLABELLED:
    process(H)
    begin
        if(rising_edge(H)) then
            if compteur1 = 15 then
                compteur1 := 0;
            else
                compteur1 := compteur1 + 1;
            end if;
            report "compteur1 = " & natural'image(compteur1);
            if (compteur1 = 9) then
                compteur2 := compteur2 + 1;
                report "compteur2 = " & natural'image(compteur2);
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
```

And that will give you multiple increments on compteur2:

> compteur.vhdl:35:13:@10ns:(report note): compteur1 = 1
>   compteur.vhdl:35:13:@30ns:(report note): compteur1 = 2
>   compteur.vhdl:35:13:@50ns:(report note): compteur1 = 3
>   compteur.vhdl:35:13:@70ns:(report note): compteur1 = 4
>   compteur.vhdl:35:13:@90ns:(report note): compteur1 = 5
>   compteur.vhdl:35:13:@110ns:(report note): compteur1 = 6
>   compteur.vhdl:35:13:@130ns:(report note): compteur1 = 7
>   compteur.vhdl:35:13:@150ns:(report note): compteur1 = 8
>   compteur.vhdl:35:13:@170ns:(report note): compteur1 = 9
>   compteur.vhdl:38:17:@170ns:(report note): compteur2 = 1
>   compteur.vhdl:35:13:@190ns:(report note): compteur1 = 10
>   compteur.vhdl:35:13:@210ns:(report note): compteur1 = 11
>   compteur.vhdl:35:13:@230ns:(report note): compteur1 = 12
>   compteur.vhdl:35:13:@250ns:(report note): compteur1 = 13
>   compteur.vhdl:35:13:@270ns:(report note): compteur1 = 14
>   compteur.vhdl:35:13:@290ns:(report note): compteur1 = 15
>   compteur.vhdl:35:13:@310ns:(report note): compteur1 = 0
>   compteur.vhdl:35:13:@330ns:(report note): compteur1 = 1
>   compteur.vhdl:35:13:@350ns:(report note): compteur1 = 2
>   compteur.vhdl:35:13:@370ns:(report note): compteur1 = 3
>   compteur.vhdl:35:13:@390ns:(report note): compteur1 = 4
>   compteur.vhdl:35:13:@410ns:(report note): compteur1 = 5
>   compteur.vhdl:35:13:@430ns:(report note): compteur1 = 6
>   compteur.vhdl:35:13:@450ns:(report note): compteur1 = 7
>   compteur.vhdl:35:13:@470ns:(report note): compteur1 = 8
>   compteur.vhdl:35:13:@490ns:(report note): compteur1 = 9
>   compteur.vhdl:38:17:@490ns:(report note): compteur2 = 2
>   compteur.vhdl:35:13:@510ns:(report note): compteur1 = 10
>   compteur.vhdl:35:13:@530ns:(report note): compteur1 = 11
>   compteur.vhdl:35:13:@550ns:(report note): compteur1 = 12
>   compteur.vhdl:35:13:@570ns:(report note): compteur1 = 13
>   compteur.vhdl:35:13:@590ns:(report note): compteur1 = 14
>   compteur.vhdl:35:13:@610ns:(report note): compteur1 = 15

And that exits normally (see the if statement in the CLOCK process).

And looking at the time stamps you'll also see that compteur1 goes to 9 on the same edge compteur2 increments on which is caused by using variables.

When using variables you might consider evaluating before incrementing:

```
UNLABELLED:
    process(H)
    begin
        if(rising_edge(H)) then
            if (compteur1 = 9) then
                compteur2 := compteur2 + 1;
                report "compteur2 = " & natural'image(compteur2);
            end if;
            if compteur1 = 15 then
                compteur1 := 0;
            else
                compteur1 := compteur1 + 1;
            end if;
            report "compteur1 = " & natural'image(compteur1);
        end if;
    end process;
```

Which will match the order as if you were using signals:

> compteur.vhdl:39:13:@490ns:(report note): compteur1 = 9
>   compteur.vhdl:32:17:@510ns:(report note): compteur2 = 2
>   compteur.vhdl:39:13:@510ns:(report note): compteur1 = 10
>   compteur.vhdl:39:13:@530ns:(report note): compteur1 = 11

Incrementing compteur2 on the next clock edge.

**And as QuantumRipple points out**

If you simply answer a question as opposed to providing complete solutions you might miss something.  In this case the effects of rollover on comptuer2, which can be cured as he indicates by doing the same thing for it:

```
    process(H)
    begin
        if rising_edge(H) then
            if compteur1 = 9 then
                if compteur2 = 15 then
                    compteur2 := 0;
                else  
                    compteur2 := compteur2 + 1;
                end if;
                report "compteur2 = " & natural'image(compteur2);
            end if;
            if compteur1 = 15 then
                compteur1 := 0;
            else
                compteur1 := compteur1 + 1;
            end if;
            report "compteur1 = " & natural'image(compteur1);
        end if;
    end process;
```

There's at least one other peculiarity that immediately comes to mind in the question's original code. Neither counter variable is involved in a signal assignment which among other things signifies no hardware will result from synthesis.

Comment: And to make this even more robust, you could add an explicit rollover to compteur2 as well. Only adding it to compteur1 will delay, not fix, the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a statement that says when computer1 = 9, then make computer 2 advance in value. That occurs only once.

Comment: but compter1 changes between 0 to 15, when reaches 15 it will turn to 0 ?

Comment: Look at your if statements. You only increment computer2 when computer1 reaches value '9'.

Comment: @邢碧舟 No. VHDL integers don't rollover automatically. You should get an error if you simulate this and attempt to increment `compter1` when it is 15. Synthesizers will ignore that, however, and allow silent rollover because there is no practical way to automatically handle that error condition in hardware. If you want rollover then you must set `compter1` to 0 when it reaches 15 or use `compter1 := (compter1 + 1) mod 16`.